# Make Backbone ignore a button or button type

Tags: backbone.js

I'm building a form and within that form is a secondary function that I wish to run. However, when I click the button for my secondary function, backbone fires and runs validation over the whole form. How do I either:

a) Make Backbone ignore that specific button and do nothing when it's clicked

or

b) (Preferred) Tie Backbone validation to only the form submit button or the button type "submit".

Example:

```
<form name="myForm" >
    <input type="text" name="yourName" ng-model="yourName" required />
    <input type="text" name="postcode" ng-model="postcode" required />
    <button id="checkPostcode" type="button" >Check Postcode</button>
    <button id="submit" type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

In this case, I only wish Backbone to run validation when the submit button is pressed, so that I can run my checkPostcode function without interference.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an eventListener to the button and prevent the default. Something like this:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click #checkPostcode": "checkPostcode"
    },

    checkPostcode: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // the actual check would go here
    }
});
```